# Won't install on an hp Pavilion with a Radeon HD6470M

Tags: installation, graphics, radeon

I have recently purchased an HP Pavilion with a Radeon HD 6470M card that is not supported. Until I found that out I reinstalled Ubuntu several times and eventually got some basic drivers to work. Due to a software I installed, I made some tweaks and broke it again, and now I can't install Ubuntu.

To try fix the problem I loaded Win7 (I'm dual booting), and reformatted (slow) the Ubuntu partition. I subsequently lost the boot for Win7, which I fixed.

However, every time I try to install Ubuntu 11.04 it either displays a black screen (doesn't even go as far as letting me choose to "use ubuntu without installing"), or stops loading saying that it has "Bad target number". I even tried the Alternate CD, which installed Ubuntu but will not go past the GRUB (even when I use "nomodeset").

I have absolutely no idea what else to try.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work out the problem.

The top row of the keyboard has the brightness and volumes, etc., keys as primary, and the Function keys (F1, F2, etc.) available when pressing the "Fn" key. So I went into the BIOS and switched them around. It turns out the the LiveCD did not like that. It obviously causes a hardware conflict, which for some reason manifests as a Radeon error (I have no idea why).

In any case, it works now.

Hope this helps people trying to reinstall Ubuntu: Make sure your BIOS is set to factory settings!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting an external monitor. Ubuntu did not appear on the laptop, but did appear on the external monitor. No clue why !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just the background-light of your screen that is not activated!?
I had such a problem with an acer-Laptop and Natty (bug in kernel):
If so, you can use a strong torch to see a little bit and start a terminal.

You have to set the backlight from terminal:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=60
```

Look here for workaround:
[Backlight workaround](http://linux-on-acer-aspire-5732z.blogspot.com/2011/06/backlight-workaround-for-linux-mint-11.html)